# Как использовать Flyouts в WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

В моей программе на *WPF* я использую библиотеку [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/). В программе есть кнопа, при нажатии на которую я хочу выводить боковое меню [Flyout](http://mahapps.com/controls/flyouts.html).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В XAML вовнутрь кода кнопки ввел следующее:

```
    <Button Height="40" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,5,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" 
            BorderThickness="1"
             Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">

        <controls:FlyoutsControl>
            <controls:FlyoutsControl>
                <controls:Flyout x:Name="yourMahAppFlyout" Header="Flyout" Position="Right" Width="200">
                    <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
                </controls:Flyout>
            </controls:FlyoutsControl>
        </controls:FlyoutsControl>
    </Button>
```

Но при нажатии на копку ничего не происходит. Я этот контрол еще не использовал, не пойму, в чем дело

Comment: А Вы уверены, что `controls:FlyoutsControl` нужно положить в кнопку? Может его надо отдельно положить и показывать/скрывать его по нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: Непонятно, куда его еще можно вставить. Если под объявлениями пространств имен, то говорит, что свойство `content` уже определено

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не работал с этой библиотекой, но судя по [документации](http://mahapps.com/controls/flyouts.html), Вы делаете что-то не так. Загляните в [пример использования `Flyout`](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/samples/MetroDemo/ExampleWindows/FlyoutDemo.xaml) и, я думаю, все встанет на свои места